# Java- reusing a thread with the same run but different parameters

Tags: java, multithreading, compression

I still have some trouble wrapping my head around threads, and I'm trying to do this in the simplest way possible. I know that threads all have to have a run method they inherited from the Runnable class, but they can have additional methods as well, correct?

The reason being, I have a thread with some private variables and a run method. It calls it's run function, and once it's done, I want to reuse the thread with the exact same run method. It does exactly the same thing, just with different variables. So can I add something like a setArray method (the thread contains a private byte array) so I can just simply call run again with this new array, or is that not allowed. I guess to put it simply, it'd be something like

```
Thread thread = new MyThread();
thread.start();

// Check if the thread has finished in a non-blocking way
if (thread.isAlive() == false) {
    thread.setArray(newArray)
    thread.start();
}
```

Basically I only have a fixed number of threads and when the first thread is done running, I want to change the parameters a bit and have it run again. I don't wan them to die, which seems to be what join does.

For the specific problem, I have say 4 threads, that each are give a set size block of a larger byte array. Each thread compresses that array with a Deflater and passes their result to a manager object that handles the synchronization. Once the first thread (as in the thread that got the first part of the array, not the first to finish) is done, it moves on to the next block not assigned to a thread.

I know thread pools are an option, but it seems a bit overkill plus I really don't understand them (I'm still having trouble with just normal threads).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, it is best to use the standard `Thread` class (don't subclass it!) and put your application code into a class that implements `Runnable`.  This makes it much easier to separate your application logic from the problem of managing the threads.

Second you have to understand that a Thread object calls the `run` method just once.  After the `run` method has returned (or terminated with an exception), the Thread object is dead, and cannot be brought back to life.

So if you want to "reuse" `Thread` instances, you have to arrange that the `run` method is a loop that (somehow) waits for the next thing to be done.  And before you know it you are *implementing* a thread pool.

There is another (more "modern") alternative to a thread pool.  Create an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instance, and use the `submit()` method to submit the `Runnable` instances for execution.  The interface javadoc has a good usage example, using an executor service instance with a private thread pool.  If you wanted to, you *could* reuse the `Runnable` instances, but generally it is simpler (and safer) to create new ones each time.

Comment: you first said -don't subclass thread- but at the end you say it simpler to create new instance each time. how can you make instance of a thread if not by implementing the thread in a subclass?

Comment: @somefolk - Read it again.  It should be clear from the context that I am talking about new instances of **`Runnable`**.  (Obvious, they will be instances of some class that implements `Runnable` ... 'cos you can't create an instance of an interface.)

Comment: What about limitations regarding the GC? When constantly creating new threads with an executor, GC throws errors.

Comment: @ylun.ca - You should be using an executor with a bounded thread pool.  The GC problem only arises if the executor creates too many threads.

Comment: Something else I should have mentioned about the above comment is that the GC is not involved with any of this.  The OOME you get when you can't launch a thread is thrown by `Thread::start()`, and it usually happens when there are too many live threads and the JVM cannot allocate a stack.  But stack space is separate from the heap and thread stacks are not managed by the GC.  (Indeed, the GC won't reclaim a thread while it is still alive ... even if the `Thread` object is not reachable from application code.)

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate class for your code that implements Runnable. You will need to make new Thread objects each time, but construct these with your single Runnable object. The run method will be reused by each Thread.

Answer (score 1):

A thread always starts exactly once, runs exactly once and then dies exactly once. So you can't call start() on the thread multiple times in the way that you suggest.

So, one way or another, you have to either:

- Have a single thread that, one way or another within its run() method, executes each of your method calls with the different sets of parameters.
- Start a new thread for each "run" (method call to the Thing That You Actually Want To Do).

Which implementation is more appropriate depends a little on your exact application. But in general, it is helpful to think of a thread as being a sub-task that runs *parallel* to other subtasks. So in general:

- if you have a series of independent "runs" of something which you have no reason to run in parallel to one another, arrange for these runs to be executed one after the other inside a single Thread.run() method;
- if you have a series of tasks that may as well run parallel to one another, put each in a separate Thread.

A thread pool is generally used for cases where at any given moment you can have some arbitrary task to execute, and such tasks can run in parallel. For example, on a typical server. Think of a web server receiving requests for pages from different clients at arbitrary points in time: each request can come at some arbitrary point in time and a request for a page from one client is completely independent from a request from another client. In principle, you don't care which requests run in parallel to which, other than that your machine has resource constraints such as the number of CPUs. For this type of case, where you effectively want to "run arbitrary tasks in arbitrary threads, up to a limit of X tasks running in parallel", you would generally use a thread pool.

Comment: I think my issues falls in the middle. I want these N blocks to compress in parallel, but at the same time I can't arbitrarily assign them because I need to keep the input and output in the same order (or else if the first thread finishes last, I'll have out of order data). I think in my case I'll just have to let them die and start a new thread for each run.

Comment: What about limitations regarding the GC? When constantly creating new threads with an executor, GC throws errors.

Answer (score -4):

Threads are basically just objects with state and a method to run. Here's an example thread:

```
public class ThreadWithState implements Runnable {

  private Object state;

  public ThreadWithState(Object state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public void run() {
    // Do something with state
  }
}
```

Threads are generally executed in parallel, otherwise the whole point of multi-threading is lost. Therefore, we try to use a pool of threads to execute, as demonstrated in the following Driver class:

```
public class Driver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadWithState thread = new ThreadWithState(null);
    ThreadWithState thread2 = new ThreadWithState(new Object());
    ThreadWithState thread3 = new ThreadWithState(new Object());
    ThreadWithState thread4 = new ThreadWithState(new Object());

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    service.submit(thread);
    service.submit(thread2);
    service.submit(thread3);
    service.submit(thread4);
    service.shutdown();
  }
}
```

Comment: how does this answer what the Op asked?